# Merge replication between Express and Enterprise editions of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, merge-replication

I have two SQL Server servers.

- 1st is an Enterprise edition and it is a local server
- 2nd is an Express edition and it is online

Now, the 1st pushes transactional replication to the 2nd.

My question: is it possible to do merge replication between those two? Can I configure the 1st server to pull changes from the 2nd server also?

And if its not possible what is the best approach to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've searched (and found, e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194380/239286), it seems not to be possible to pull changes from the SQL Express Edition back to the Enterprise (or Standard) Editions. Although MS states that Merge-Replications would be possible.

I think the root cause is that the Express Edition dosn't have a "Agent", which is needed to publish/distrbute changes.

I can't give any recommendation to what would be the best way to solve this issue programmatically. One way would (could?) be to change your second SQL-Server from Express to a Standard Edition (untested), at least that's what we are aiming to.

See also these regarding this topic:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/is-merge-replication-available-in-sql-server-express#post-906916
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ade52f9-84fd-47a1-a9d1-c5a15b968520/merge-replication-with-sql-express

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm still looking . Mean while I managed to do manual sync (programmatically) for some tables but it is a headache. Stander Edition license MORE money! which is clients nightmare :)